# How to draw unity gizmos with new input system?

Tags: unity, input, events, debugging

I am using the new Unity Input system for my game.

When I press a key, for example "Q", I want gizmos to be drawn.

However, I can't subscribe to a keypress event with a Gizmo drawing function, because it says it needs to be inside of OnDrawGizmos(). Furthermore, I can't subscribe with that function because it says it doesn't take any parameters, and I need to pass `InputAction.CallbackContext context` as a parameter, for it to be considered okay by the event system.

Here's the code for how I did it before:

```
public void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
    {
        DrawStuff();
    }
}
```

How can I recreate this?

Comment: Have you considered setting a variable in the input response function, and checking that variable in OnDrawGizmos?

Comment: I will try to do that now. However that seems like a pretty big workaround, I thought there was some other method to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I explained in [my answer to your previous question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/189462/21890), you generally should try to avoid thinking of input in terms of keypresses and more in terms of semantic actions. But in this particular case you are talking about the `OnDrawGizmos` editor-feature your actual players are not going to see anyway, so it's no big deal to go for a hackish solution. The 1:1 equivalent of the above code with the new Input API would be:

```
public void OnDrawGizmos()
{
     if (Keyboard.current[Key.Q].isPressed) {
         DrawStuff();
     }
}
```

For more information:

- The [Migration Guide](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Migration.html) from the old to the new input system (but keep in mind that  most of the things described there are no longer best practice!)
- Documentation for [`Keyboard`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.Keyboard.html?q=Keyboard) (which is unfortunately a total mess). `.current` is the current keyboard (the new input system API is already designed with future support for multiple keyboards in mind, but currently the engine does not support more than one)
- Documentation for [`KeyControl`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.Controls.KeyControl.html) (which tells you what else you can do with a specific keyboard key)

Comment: Thank you, This is exactly what I was looking for. Hackish or not, it's not shown to players so this seems like the best and easiest way to do it.