# Unity Input System: How to handle input from specific device types when the binding abstraction fails?

Tags: unity, input, mouse, keyboard

Is there a way for Input System code to determine what kind of device generated an Input Action's current event, so that it can be filtered based on device type?

The example I have is an Orbit Camera that is controlled by either the mouse or the keyboard cursor keys. Normally the camera is static, but rotates around a target object if the cursor keys are pressed, using a 2D Vector Composite binding. Also, if the mouse is moved, it rotates too, according to the mouse delta x & y values. Both these bindings are part of the same InputAction.

The problem occurs when I want to make the mouse move the camera *only* if the mouse button is pressed. But I still want the keyboard cursor keys to work regardless of the mouse button state. In this case, my code needs to know that one of the bindings on the InputAction is a mouse, and that input events from it should be ignored unless some other condition (from an InputAction bound to the mouse button) is active.

I understand that Input System is meant to abstract away a lot of the details of the input devices, and in most cases it does. But in this case, the way a human uses the mouse vs. the keyboard is fundamentally different, because the mouse is not dedicated to moving the camera, but the keyboard cursor keys are. I can't see a standard or even simple way to implement this. The best I've come up with is a pair of InputActions - one for "anytime" (the keyboard cursor keys) and another for "gated" (the mouse delta), with an extra InputAction to define the gate (mouse button). Then the code filters and combines the inputs from both of these to determine the final effect. It's not very elegant.

How feasible would it be to create a custom controller for the mouse that only generates delta movement input when the mouse button is held? Then this could be bound to the original single InputAction. Is this a thing people do with Input System?

Comment: Mouse deltas and keyboard inputs won't be in the same range anyway - the mouse delta will be in pixels, and you'll scale that differently based on things like screen resolution or sensitivity settings. Implementing them as two separate actions as you've done sounds like the right approach - and once you've scaled them to the right game units, they can both call into a shared function that handles the rotation itself.  But you may be able to use a [Custom Composite](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/ActionBindings.html#writing-custom-composites) if you want.

Comment: @DMGregory thank you. Fair comment, although it turns out it's easy to modulate your mouse movement speed so that it appears to be about the same speed as the cursor keys. Or put another way, the cursor speed is constant, and the mouse speed is very variable and nuanced, even if sharing the same sensitivity scaling. A lucky situation I guess. Anyway, using separate actions seems OK to me if that's what I have to do. Thanks for the link to Custom Composites, they do sound interesting. Something like "Button with one modifier" but "Vector2 with one modifier" might do the trick, if I go that way.